# Why is it "sequacity" and not "sequenicity"?

Tags: adjectives

I'm trying to form a sentence along the following lines:

"the difference between **sequence** and synchronicity is important when it comes to understanding..."

I'm unsure of the proper use of the word "sequence" in this sentence. I'm comparing it to "synchronicity" and immediately thought that the word "sequence", would become "sequenicity". But the dictionary tells me different, "sequacity". I'm not debating that it isn't the correct word, as the word "sequenicity" doesn't exist, it's just not what I expected.

Comment: It's derived from a Latin adjective, *sequax* ("following") http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sequacity

Comment: What meaning are you looking for? Does it have something to do with 'being in a sequence'. If so then almost all the words you've mentioned are not relevant (in addition to being pretty rare).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**sequacity** and **sequacious**, meaning obsequiousness/servile following of others/thoughtless, uncritical acceptance  is somewhat archaic.

**sequenicity** is ... to put it bluntly 'not a word' (meaning it is not really accepted, not in any dictionary, prescriptive, descriptive or otherwise) and is actually not used by anybody. It looks like a neologism or a malformed attempt at making a regular extension of **sequence**.

If the latter, then the appropriate extension of **sequence** to an adjective would be

> **sequential**

and from that to a noun for the concept would be

> **sequentiality**

Because this started from *sequence*, all the derivations use 'e' instead of 'a'.

Comment: So if I were to write a sentence "the difference between sequentiality and synchronicity is important when it comes to understanding..." - which would be the correct word to use? Sequentiality I presume?

Comment: You should definitely use *sequentiality*. Looking in old dictionaries in Google books, in the mid-19th century, when it was used the most, *sequacity* meant *lack of originality* or *pliancy*. It has since fallen out of use, but I don't believe the meaning has shifted.

Comment: Great, thanks. I've marked this as the accepted answer as it it helped me to understand the differences a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

Sequacity does not proceed from sequence directly. It comes from **Sequacious**. Both have roots in the same Latin word.

Sequacious: following with smooth or logical regularity.

Therefore, a sequence is sequacious.

Comment: The primary dictionary meaning of _sequacious_ is [intellectually servile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sequacious). (other dictionaries give alternates that are closer to 'sequence' ([following with smooth or logical regularity. ](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sequacious) )